# ActiveModel - `undefined method `write_from_user' for nil:NilClass`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have simple class:

```rb
class Settings
  include ActiveModel::Model, ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :display_raw_results, :boolean, default: false
end
```

When I try to initialize it with empty hash it works.

```rb
Settings.new
# or
Settings.new({})
```

But if I pass a value in this hash it fails with expection

```rb
Settings.new(display_raw_results: true) 
# results in:  undefined method `write_from_user' for nil:NilClass
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in one line `include`. After including modules separately it works as expected.

```rb
class Settings
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :display_raw_results, :boolean, default: false
end
```

Comment: I think that also order of includes matters: if I include `ActiveModel::Attrbiutes` first, it also fails with the same error.